# why can use array's push

Tags: solidity, remix-tests

```
//一个投票的合约
contract Ballot{
    
    //提案对象
    struct Proposal{
        bytes32 name;
        uint voteCount;//累计票数
    }

    
    //获取获胜的对象
    function winningProposal() public view returns (Proposal[] memory)
    {
        Proposal[] memory win;
        uint winningVoteCount = 0;
        for(uint i=0;i < proposals.length;i++){
            if(proposals[i].voteCount > winningVoteCount){
                winningVoteCount = proposals[i].voteCount;
            }
        }

        for(uint m=0; m < proposals.length; m++){
            if(winningVoteCount == proposals[m].voteCount){
                // push can't use
                win.push(proposals[m]);
                // next line can use
                // win[win.length] = proposals[m];
            }
        }
        

        return win;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.16/types.html?highlight=Push#allocating-memory-arrays

> As opposed to storage arrays, it is not possible to resize memory arrays (e.g. the .push member functions are not available).